# How can i make Bootstrap 3 desktop first instead of mobile first?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am working on this responsive design for an ASP.Net website at work which needs to work with IE8 as well, Everything is working fine in every other browser except in IE8 the post back events make the page loading in Mobile view and then changing into desktop view pretty much visible to the user, which i assume is because Respond.js is taking time to kick into action.

Hence i am thinking to change the media queries in a way that the design works with desktop first. But i need to know is this the right way to go or maybe i should switch back to Bootstrap 2.3 or some other framework maybe. But i am almost in the stage of completing my design.

I can use separate style sheet, but the requirement is superfluously the responsiveness needs to work in IE8 as well.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I could be wrong but what device (still?) uses IE8 to necessitate _responsiveness_ for that client?

Comment: @EdSF Actually I think he need to support IE8 in a PC but be responsive with mobile with other browsers too. The problem is that the page render looking like mobile at first and IE8 take time to adapt to the desktop size.

Comment: @EdSF i understand what you are saying, still the pages in the design are postback heavy and the first loading in mobile view is a problem that i am still looking for a way to rectify.

Comment: I think you already know your path. You shouldn't "sacrifice" the kitchen sink for some "obscure" client/requirement (of course base this on your analytics data). You can tinker with [ways to detect/handle IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pick the approach that best meet your requirements. Hth.